# what is the ENV in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at someone else's app that has a ENV variable in a lot of files. I know that it's an obj because it's using `[...]` to locate things but I couldn't find anything with `def ENV` or `ENV =` with fuzzy search. Is this a Rails specific object that's everywhere and you can just throw things in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ENV it's not Rails specific, it's Ruby object to access the system environment variables.

Look the documentation [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.5/ENV.html)

Comment: Thansk! How do I see a list of all keys and values on it? Would i just pry into the piece of code that calls it and explore it there?

Comment: @stackjlei sure. Or from a Linux / Unix terminal in one line `echo "p ENV.keys" | ruby` - remove `.keys` to see also the values of the system (but it would be outside your Rails app) - so the pry-way is good